# Package delay to Mils conversion

Tags: xilinx, delay, virtex-series-fpga

I was able to calculate the package delay values in pico seconds by using the IBIS models from the xilinx site.

For example:

For a Virtex-5 FPGA IBIS model, the package ff323_5vlx20t_ibis.pkg is provided. Let us choose the pin B9.

From Capacitance matrix, C=1.58E-12 F/package length

From Inductance matrix, L=1.99E-09 H/package length

Delay= SQRT(C*L)=56.1 ps

Now I want convert this delay(56.1 ps) to package length(mils).

What method I need to follow for the same?

Comment: As the distance involved is used to equalise the timing across a group of signals and the internal package timing is fixed, convert it to the equivalent length of track on the PCB.

Comment: @PeterSmith I will convert the propagation delay value 160ps/inch to 1 pico seconds per mil, then multiply that value with 56.1ps to obtain length in mils. is it correct ?